# can sas6 and perc6 function together?

Tags: installation

I have a Dell Precision T7500. It comes with SAS hostadaptor but that only supports RAID 0 and RAID 1.  It has 4 connectors. (must be built in controller as I see no card). The motherboard has a few SATA ports for CD/DVD/etc/.

I want to add a RAID cfg to the setup so I bought a PERC6 card.

Do I have to disable SAS in the BIOS to get the PERC 6 card to using RAID 5/10/etc?

I want data on RAID 5/10/etc array and the OS on a mirror.

I have setup Win7Pro 64 bit on 1 drive (removed second drive from the internal SAS as installing was taking forever with 2 drives attached). The SAS program only shows ability to boot to 1/2 drives, do not know where the option is/ways to configure a RAID mirror for the OS

Comment: The actual authoritative answer would come from Dell.  Have you contacted or emailed them asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

Generally: No problem.  You can add more cards and thus add more functionality.

In the case of card from which you boot you might need to change the boot priority in the BIOS. (If you do not boot from it then there is no need to do this).

However @mdpc is right in that this is a very specific question which you can (should) ask of Dell. I had boor experience with Dells consumer service, but their server and workstation support seems fine. (and a T7500 is a workstation).

> SAS program only shows abilty to boot to 1/2 drives.

To comment on this we need a lot more information. E.g. is the drive in mirror mode, in a stripe? As JBOD?

> do not know where the option is/ways to configure a raid mirror for the OS.

There are a lot of options, from letting the hardware (e.g. the PERC) present a single disk to the OS while it is really a RAID array, to solving it in windows via disk management.

Since the PERC 6 comes with on board cache memory I suggest moving **all** drives to the PERC6's ports, configuring the RAID array for your OS mirror and your data array and then reinstalling windows on the OS mirror.